# Create array from another with specific indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, one of data and one of indices:

```
var data = [
    'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' '
];
var indices = [
    4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2
];
```

I would like to create a third array, using cells of `data` in order indicated in `indices`, so it here it would be:

```
['o', 'h', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l']
```

I know I could easily do it with a simple loop:

```
var newArray = new Array(indices.length);
for (var i in indices) {
    var index = indices[i];
    newArray.push(data[index]);
}
```

But I wonder if there is a cleaner/simpler way to do it, like an array method or a special constructor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like so

```js
var data = [
    'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' '
];

var indices = [
    4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2
];

var res = indices.map(function (el) {
  return data[el];
});

console.log(res);
```

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use map

```
var newArray = indices.map(function(i){
    return data[i]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have used while loop:

```js
var data = [
  'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' '
];
var indices = [
  4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2
];
var l = indices.length,
  newArray = [];
while (l--)
  newArray[l] = data[indices[l]];
console.log(newArray);
```